# Batch Script responds with "Error opening script file" when opening FTP file

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a Batch file to upload files from a folder on my computer.

When I call the FTP Script to do the upload:

```
FTP -v -i -s:ftp.txt
```

or

```
FTP -v -i -s:c:\path\to\file\ftp.txt
```

Neither of those works, and instead

```
Error opening script file: ftp.txt
```

is returned.

Strange thing is, that the exact same script is being executed without problems on another computer.

Opening the batch file with admin-rights does not help. I'm running Windows 10.

Edit: The ftp.txt looks like this:

```
open ##host##
##user##
##password##

lcd c:\local\path\
cd  path/on/server/
binary
mput "*.xxx"
disconnect
bye
```

Comment: Is the script file saved as an ascii text file?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the original post with the contents of the ftp.txt

Answer (score 1):

Make a new, empty file with `echo >ftp.test` and try with that file.

If that gives you the same error, you'll need to look at your execution environment (look at `set` and the process owner of `cmd.exe`). It's also possible that the `ftp` command is being run as a user that doesn't have access to that file.

If you don't get an error then it's probably either a file-permissions or special-character issue with ftp.txt. Retyping the same content into a different file will get around those issues. Remember not to copy/paste because you could accidentally copy invisible special characters that you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I'm not expirienced enough to check all these things, though.
I created a new .bat file containing "echo >ftp.test". It doesn't do anything when executed.
"look at set and the process owner of cmd.exe" - I don't know what to do here. How do I find out if the user who runs the ftp-command has access to the file (the script can copy files from another directory to this one, so I guess it does?).

Retyping the ftp.txt did not work :/

Comment: Make a new, empty file called emptyfile.txt. Run `FTP -v -i -s:emptyfile.txt`. Let me know what happens.If you find yourself typing "didn't work" or "nothing happened" then hit backspace a few times and instead describe what *did* happen. This will help to narrow down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to this conversation since there have been a lot of views and no solution. I had the same response and it wasn't a permissions issue. It was also no the text file that was the issue because it never technically reached the text file. It was the path to the text file. The following for me didn't work. I had to put quotations around the path even though there were no spaces to confuse the command line.

- What you tried:

  `FTP -v -i -s:c:\path\to\file\ftp.txt`
- What I tried and worked. *(I didn't need to use `-v`, mine works without it)*

  `FTP -i -s:"c:\path\to\file\ftp.txt"`

Running the file acted normal for me. My issue was trying to run the batch file through Windows Task Manager. Somehow, this was causing it to lose the text file somehow. I hope this helps anyone else who reads this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the .txt file path in the "Start In" section for it to work in Windows Task Manager. No problems since.